# Detecting register_argc_argv in PHP

Tags: php

I need to check if register_argc_argv is enabled in my PHP application installer.

I wrote a code, but it's not working. It always saying it's disabled while it's enabled already in php.ini:

```
 //register_argc_argv
echo "<register_argc_argv>";
$ok=0;
$val="Disabled";
if(key_exists('PHP Core', $phpinfo))
{
    if(key_exists('register_argc_argv', $phpinfo['PHP Core']))
    {
            if(is_array($phpinfo['coreKey']['register_argc_argv']))
            {
                    if($phpinfo['coreKey']['register_argc_argv'][0]=="On")
                {
                    $ok=1;
                    $val="Enabled";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($phpinfo['coreKey']['register_argc_argv']=="On")
                {
                    $ok=1;
                    $val="Enabled";
                }
            }
    }
}
echo "<val>$val</val><ok>$ok</ok>";
echo "</register_argc_argv>\n";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use PHP's [ini_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) method to determine if it is set.

```
<?php
  if(ini_get("register_argc_argv")) {
    echo "It's set! :)";
  } else {
    echo "It isn't set! :(";
  }
```

Comment: Then I do not really understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to figure out if the PHP configuration setting "register_argc_argv" is set then my code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with `ini_get('register_argc_argv');`?